# Condition on numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays with the same number of elements

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Y = [10,4,3,7,7,3,1,8,98]
```

I would like to keep the elements of X and Y such as `2<X<7`. How can I do?

Ok it works well with

```
 Y = Y[np.logical_and(X>2, X<5)]
 X = X[np.logical_and(X>2, X<5)]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try a filter? What you are showing are just lists.

Comment: Yes sorry it is a simple python list but if the solution is simpler  with numpy I can use numpy array. With only one condition it's easy .I can use X = X[X>2]. I thought another similar way was possible with two values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
>>> X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> X[np.logical_and(X>2, X<7)]
array([3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Or, with fewer keystrokes: `X[(X>2) & (X<7)]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a loop and  `if` ,and also you can use `set()` for keep the deferent indexes :

```
>>> X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> Y = [10,4,3,7,7,3,1,8,98]
>>> X=[i for i in X if 2<i<7]
>>> Y=[i for i in Y if 2<i<7]
>>> X
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> Y
[4, 3, 3]
>>> set(Y)
set([3, 4])
```

Comment: If I use this method I do not have anymore the same number of elements in each arrays. In fact I want to show only a selected region (in X) of a X,Y plot

Comment: you are not forced to use `set` ? ?

Comment: I want to keep the corresponding indexes. If you look at the first index that fullfill the condition on X it is 3, the corresponding number on Y is 3 also but with this method it is not the case after filtering